# Resultado en Ajax multiplicando los valores de array

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, array

Al hacer una consulta a la base de datos, genera una respuesta que es recibida por la función success de ajax, pero cuando quiero poner **$.each**, no es que tenga un problema con eso, no y no, el json está parseado, todo anda bien, sólo que genera más respuestas de las que el servidor da, por ejemplo, de respuesta sale un sólo mensaje y devuelve 11 aproximadamente.

```js
success: function(response){

    $this = $(this).children(".messages");
    response = JSON.parse(response);

    $.each(response, function(){
      console.log(response);
      $('<div class="message-sent">' + response.message + '</div>').appendTo($this);
    })
  $this.append(response);
 }
```

Tal como puse arriba, primero hago un console.log, el array aparece con la misma cantidad de resultados que entrega la respuesta, pero al ser enviados por $.each se multiplican infinitamente, o sea. help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé exactamente cuál es la constitución de tu JSON. Lo cierto es que tienes al parecer una duplicidad de append.

Lo más limpio es que dentro del bucle concatenes los datos en una variable, y luego, fuera del bucle actualices el contenedor o elemento con esa información. Hacer un append cada vez  dentro de un bucle no es recomendado, dado que modificas el DOM en cada iteracción.

Aquí he simulado un JSON, para mostrar una forma de leerlo, tomando la clave `message` del mismo, concatenando en el bucle y luego fuera de él actualizamos el div cuyo id es `response` en el DOM.

Puedes aplicar esta solución en tu código. Si no funciona, por favor comparte la estructura de tu JSON y explica claramente en qué contenedor quieres poner el contenido que extraes en el `each`.

```js
var response = `[{ "id" : "1", "message" : "message1" },
  { "id" : "2", "message" : "message2" },
  { "id" : "3", "message" : "message3" }]`;
var json = JSON.parse(response);
var divResponse = $('#response');

var html = "";

$(json).each(function(i, val) {
  html += val.message+"<br />";
  console.log(val.message);
});
divResponse.append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba cambiando la forma de recorrer la respuesta por esto

```
response.forEach( (element) => {
  console.log(element);
})
```

Ademas de quitar el `response = JSON.parse(response);`

[Aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ejemplo-json-response?file=index.js) te dejo un codigo de ejemplo. Espero te sirva.